# HTTP Status 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: server, java, error-handling, tomcat, tomcat8

After a lot of struggle, I have installed Tomcat8 on my Ubuntu.
However it results in the following error when I access

> localhost:8080

**HOW DO I FIX IT**?

```
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all?  Seemed related to your issue

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm too new here to comment and suggest that this is a possible duplicate of another question - you might take a look at this Question and it's answers - looks like a class file is possibly corrupted.  Does Tomcat run fine if you dont try and navigate to your application, e.g. can you get to the admin web pages?  Have a lok at this - hope it helps [Tomcat suddenly throwing a ClassFormatError on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346923/tomcat-suddenly-throwing-a-classformaterror-on-startup)